# Evitar que safari "reaccione" al usar el touch en BODY

Tags: javascript, html5, ios, css3

Estoy haciendo una webAPP, y usando el safari (en un iPAD) ocurre que usando el touchpad en BODY, donde no haya ningún otro elemento, el navegador "reacciona", parece que "seleccione" todos los elementos o algo similar.
Además, dejando pulsado el touchpad, aparece el menú contextual ( En Android no aparece pero el telefono reacciona vibrando.

Me gustaría evitar estas dos cosas, **sin usar** librerías ni frameworks.

Aquí os dejo un vídeo donde muestro mi problema: [Enlace](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hcOsDQbjBmQ)

Y aquí un código de ejemplo (el que se ve en el vídeo), con las soluciones que he intentado, capturando eventos y con propiedades CSS, pero no parece funcionar.

```js
document.ontouchmove = function(event){event.preventDefault();}
document.onmousedown = function(event){event.preventDefault();}
document.onclick = function(event){event.preventDefault();}
document.ondblclick = function(event){event.preventDefault();}
document.oncontextmenu = function(event){event.preventDefault();}
document.ondrag = function(event){event.preventDefault();}
 
function colorRandom(){
  var color=["red","green","blue","yellow","orange","cyan"];
  IDpantalla.style.backgroundColor=color[Math.floor(Math.random()*color.length)];
}
IDpantalla.ontouchmove=function(){colorRandom();};
IDpantalla.onclick=function(){colorRandom();};
```

```css
BODY {
 background-color:silver;
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -khtml-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
 -webkit-user-drag: none;
}
#IDpantalla {
 position:fixed;
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 background-color:salmon;
}
```

```html
<HEAD>
 <META name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1.0 user-scalable=0"> 
 <META name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
 <META name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
 <META name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
</HEAD>
<BODY>
  <DIV id="IDpantalla"></DIV>
</BODY>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Ver Demo](http://jsbin.com/tupivozace/11/edit?css,js,output)**

La solución es de seleccionar `html` y en javascript `window`.

**CSS**

```
html {      
    background-color:silver;  
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
}

#IDpantalla {
    position:fixed;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:salmon;

}
```

**JS**

```
var IDpantalla = document.getElementById('IDpantalla');

window.ontouchmove = function(event){event.preventDefault();}
window.onmousedown = function(event){event.preventDefault();}
window.onclick = function(event){event.preventDefault();}
window.ondblclick = function(event){event.preventDefault();}
window.oncontextmenu = function(event){event.preventDefault();}
window.ondrag = function(event){event.preventDefault();}

// Para evitar la vibracion al mantener presionado el touchPad
// en  Android, capturar el evento document.ontouchstart
document.ontouchstart = function(event){event.preventDefault();}

function colorRandom(){
  var color=["red","green","blue","yellow","orange","cyan"];
  IDpantalla.style.backgroundColor=color[Math.floor(Math.random()*color.length)];
}
IDpantalla.ontouchmove=function(){colorRandom();};
IDpantalla.onclick=function(){colorRandom();};
```

*Nota aparte: No uses letras mayúscula en los tags*

Comment: Estupendo, gracias.
En Android sigue vibrando al dejar pulsado, ¿alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Lo siento... pero en Android no te puedo ayudar.. porque no tengo ningún dispositivo para probarlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias igualmente :)

Comment: Y con eso funciona en los dos dispositivos? Si es así.. estas libre de editar la respuesta si deseas...

Comment: Para evitar la vibracion al mantener presionado el touchPad en Android, capturar el evento document.ontouchstart